# Should.js compare Object's properties using containsDeep

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, mocha.js, should.js

I've got a class that has several properties, set like so:

```
var MyClass = function(opts) {
    var self = this

    // orgId and appId are required
    self.orgId = ok(arguments).getIfExists('0') || ok(opts).getIfExists('orgId') || ok(config).getIfExists('orgId')
    self.appId = ok(arguments).getIfExists('1') || ok(opts).getIfExists('appId') || ok(config).getIfExists('appId')

    ... etc.

    return self
}
```

I'm creating a shared instance of this class like so:

```
var SharedInstance = {
    initSharedInstance: function(opts) {
        Object.setPrototypeOf(SharedInstance, new MyClass(opts))
    }
}
```

This works quite well.

I'm writing some tests that compare the properties to those in a config file to ensure that upon initialization, the properties match:

```
it('SharedInstance\'s properties should match those defined in config.json', function() {
    SharedInstance.orgId.should.equal(config.orgId)
    SharedInstance.appId.should.equal(config.appId)
    SharedInstance.clientId.should.equal(config.clientId)
    SharedInstance.clientSecret.should.equal(config.clientSecret)
    SharedInstance.baseUrl.should.equal(config.baseUrl)
    SharedInstance.tokenTtl.should.equal(config.tokenTtl)
    SharedInstance.authFallback.should.equal(config.authFallback)
})
```

To make this more concise and scalable, I'd like to be able to use [should.js](/questions/tagged/should.js)'s `containsDeep` instead:

```
it('SharedInstance\'s properties should match those defined in config.json', function() {
    SharedInstance.should.deepContains(config)
})
```

The problem is that the only property that exists on `SharedInstance` directly is `initSharedInstance`. I've tried comparing to `SharedInstance.prototype` and `SharedInstance.constructor`, but neither work. How can I grab the prototype properties defined on the parent `MyClass` to allow this test to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `deepContains` actually works just fine, but what was missing, was an initializer call in my subclass.

The solution is to call the super `MyClass.call(self)`:

```
var SharedInstance = {
    initSharedInstance: function(opts) {
        var self = this
        Object.setPrototypeOf(SharedInstance, new MyClass(opts))
        // this was missing:
        MyClass.call(self)
    }
}
```